# How should i solve Exception "Unable to resolve path" while executing a query in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, entity, dao

I am trying to test a simple application that uses hibernate and annotations.I have the follwing database tables with the following foreign key constraints.

```
create table user_info 
(
mobile_number varchar(16) primary key, 
gender char(1),
language varchar(4))


create table user_order_info
(order_id integer(16) not null primary key auto_increment,   
mobile_number varchar(16) not null,
location_name varchar(32) not null, 
foreign key(mobile_number) references user_info(mobile_number),

create table user_queue_order_info
(queue_id integer(16) not null primary key auto_increment,
order_id integer(16),   
mobile_number varchar(16) not null,  
order_value integer(8) not null,   
foreign key(mobile_number) references user_info(mobile_number),
foreign key(order_id) references user_order_info(order_id) on delete cascade)
```

And the respective entity table of the above table are as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_info")
public class UserInfo implements Serializable {         
private String mobileNumber;    
private char gender;
private String language;
    //getters and setters and constructors
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_order_info")

public UserOrderInfo implements Serializable {  
private long orderId;
private String locationName;        
private UserInfo userInfo;
    //getters and setters and constructors
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_queue_order_info")

public class UserQueueOrderInfo implements Serializable {   

private long queueId;   
private int orderValue; 
private UserInfo userInfo;
private UserOrderInfo userOrderinfo;
    //getters and setters , constructors
```

The problem is  whenI try to use UserOrderInfoDao to access the database by using the following method, exception is coming.

```
public UserOrderInfo UserOrderInfoByMobileNumber(String mobileNumber ) {
List<UserOrderInfo> userOrderInfoList =    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from UserOrderInfo where userInfo.mobileNumber='"+mobileNumber+"'").list();
    if(!userOrderInfoList.isEmpty()){
        return userOrderInfoList.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

When i try to debug by tracing the exception,the exception coming is:

> Exception Unable to resolve path [userInfo.mobileNumber], unexpected token [userInfo]   [from com.appls.entity.UserOrderInfo where userInfo.mobileNumber='7770909090']

why is this problem is coming?I am waiting for your valuble suggestions.

And I have done the mappings in getters and setters in the following way:

```
@Id 
@Column(name = "mobile_number")
public String getMobileNumber() {
    return mobileNumber;
}
```

Same for other fields also.

Entity for User_info is

```
    private String mobileNumber;        
private char gender;
private String language;

@Id 
@Column(name = "mobile_number")
public String getMobileNumber() {
    return mobileNumber;
}
public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
}

@Column(name = "gender")
public char getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(char gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

@Column(name = "language")
public String getLanguage() {
    return language;
}
public void setLanguage(String language) {
    this.language =language;
}

public UserInfo() {
    super();        
}


public UserInfo(String mobileNumber){
    super();
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
}

public UserInfo(String mobileNumber, char gender, String language) {
    super();
    this.mobileNumber =mobileNumber;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.language = language;

}   

@Override
public String toString() {
return "{\"mobileNumber\": \"" + this.mobileNumber
            + "\", \"gender\": \"" + this.gender
            + "\", \"language\": \"" + this.language }";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

either change  `private String mobileNumber;` including getter/setter

as `private String mobile_number;`

Or annotate it

```
@Column(name="mobile_number")
private String mobileNumber;
```

Same with `private String locationName;` and `private String orderValue;`

Query should be like  `createQuery("from UserOrderInfo userOrderInfo where userOrderInfo.userInfo.mobileNumber='"+mobileNumber+"'").list()`

Comment: yeah i have used@Id 
 @Column(name = "mobile_number")
 public String getMobileNumber() {
  return mobileNumber;
 }

Comment: so you are annotating getters? can you post full entities.

Comment: Yeah i have updated the getters and setters method.There I have done the mappings

Comment: try `createQuery("from UserOrderInfo userOrderInfo where userOrderInfo.userInfo.mobileNumber='"+mobileNumber+"'").list()`

Comment: Exception is coming when I try in that way also. The exception is Exception could not resolve property: userInfo of: com.appls.entity.UserOrderInfo  [from com.appls.entity.UserOrderInfo  UserOrderInfo where userOrderInfo.userInfo.mobileNumber='9888000001']

Comment: please post the UserOrderInfo.java with getters as well, I doubt you mapping is wrong .

Answer (score 0):

you should change your mobileNumber field as mobile_number in DB or in pojo by annotation.